# Specifying a SSL/TLS certificate for Docker containers and Dockerfile in Windows

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm very new to SSL/TLS certificates so please bear with me.

I've been having TLS issues with various package managers on my work laptop. I figured out that the laptop has a corporate certificate. I've successfully exported the certificate to a `.crt` file and have solved the problem with `npm` and `yarn` (`npm config -g set cafile C:\Users\youruser\.certificates\yourcertname.crt`). However, I'm still having problems with Docker, specifically my `Dockerfile` builds. I've seen in other posts to copy the cert into the container, but the build is being done on both the laptop and an Ubuntu server, where the cert doesn't exist and isn't needed. I know I can do `npm set config strict-ssl false`, but I also need to install `bash` and can't do so without triggering `apk` SSL errors. Is there a way to specify the certificate elsewhere?

Comment: Certificates for servers reached by apk/npm should be trusted certificates by default. It sounds like your company has setup some kind of MITM SSL inspection proxy. That's the only reason I can think this would happen.

Comment: Let's say that's the problem, is there anything I can do about it without getting rid of the proxy?

Comment: Hard to say for sure without knowing exactly what kind of proxy is being used. But you should be able to use your own proxy on localhost that moves through the MITM proxy on behalf of your containers. Configure your docker daemon/containers to use the HTTP(S) proxy on your localhost. You can put whatever certs/auth are necessary in your localhost proxy so you don't have to do it in your containers/docker build process. Or configure the corporate proxy settings as appropriate. You can set proxy settings in the docker daemon config.